# Реализация интерфейса System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, .net

Хочу создать класс, реализующий System.IO.Stream, вопрос. Как в этом классе читать данные из файла? Существуют ли более низкоуровневые функции для чтения/записи из/в файла/файл?
Или мне в самой реализации использовать например StreamReader, StreamWriter?

Comment: А чем Вам не угодил [`FileStream`][1]? Это как раз реализация `System.IO.Stream` для работы с файлами.


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

Comment: Пишу поток zlib только для себя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffered Reader